# how can i change class by get element by id in angular 8 and change the style of div

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

How can I add and remove class by getElementBy id in angular 8.
I want to remove class 'col-md-12' and add 'col-md-6' when the user click the details icon.

and also change the style of another div like display: block.

component.html

```
 <div class="col-md-12" id="demo">
      <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8 mt-5">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>###</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let user of usersArray" >
              <td>
                {{user.score}}
              </td>
              <td>
                <i class="material-icons text-primary pointer" (click)="details()">account_circle</i>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
```

after the changing class, I want to show this div

```
  <div class="col-md-6" style="display: none;" >
        <div class="userDetails">
            <img src="../../assets/images/user.png">
            <span class="mx-3"> <b>Shubham Patil</b></span>
            <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8 mt-4">
              <table class="table table-striped rounded">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Topics</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr >
                    <td>
                      Why me
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      300
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

component.ts

```
element: HTMLElement;

 details(){
    this.element = document.getElementById('demo').removeClass("col-md-12") as HTMLElement;
    this.element = document.getElementById('demo').addClass("col-md-6") as HTMLElement;
    console.log("change")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try so:

In template:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="demo" #demo>
   ...
   <td>
    <i class="material-icons text-primary pointer" (click)="details(demo)">account_circle</i>
   </td>
   ...
</div>
```

and in .ts

```
details(elem: HTMLElement) {
  console.log(elem.className, 'before');
  elem.className = 'col-md-6';
  console.log(elem.className, 'after');
}
```

Comment: Thank you @qwerty it's working. And I want to show another div on details function how I can do this

Comment: details(elem1, elem2, elem3, ...)

Comment: but what you do like that, is not best practices.  What do you want in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can simple use the angular's ngClass directive by using a condition. Kindly see the below mentioned reference https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0):

The "Angular" way to do this would be to bind variables in the component file to the template using Angular's template language. See [template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) in the Angular docs for more info.

component.html

```
 <div id="demo"
    [class.col-md-12]="!isShowingDetails"
    [class.col-md-6]="isShowingDetails"> <!--"[class.my-class-name] syntax to dynamically add or remove classes based on if the value assigned to the property is true/false -->
      <div >
        ...
            <tr *ngFor="let user of usersArray" >
              <td>
                <i class="material-icons" (click)="showDetails()">account_circle</i>
              </td>
            </tr>
         ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf="isShowingDetails"> <!--ADDED *ngIf directive to show and hide details HTML -->
        <div class="userDetails">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
    ...
})
class MyComponent {
    isDisplayingDetails = false;

    showDetails() {
        isDisplayingDetails = true;
    }

}
```

See [class binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding) and [*ngIf](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif) for more info.